# Automatic removal of several lines in many .csv files

Tags: csv, cmd

I have 1200 csv files and each of these files statrs from 3 lines which I would like to delete. Is it possible to make it automatically by any CMD command or special program? 
I combine all of 1200 files into one by CMD command `copy *.CSV   combine.csv` but this file is too big to open by Excel, Word, Notepad++ or Microsoft Notepad.

Comment: `type win.ini | more +3`

Comment: Should I type this command in my files directory in command line or where?

Comment: Type it in `C:\windows` or type anywhere `type c:\windows\win.ini | more +3`. See `More /?`, `For /?` (the other thing you need to know), and https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/12/command-prompt-cheat-sheet.html.

Comment: The first program posted to that website is cut

Comment: `for /?` and `more /?` should provide enough information to make it work.

Comment: Removing the first three (3) lines from each file is not difficult. But, that is likely to still produce a file that is too large to open in the applications you mentioned. What is your plan if that is the result?

Comment: @lit I have 1200 files each of it consist of 1 000 000 rows with data. I would like to delete this first 3 rows, combine all 1200 files into 1 file and this file load into any math program (like Matlab) to get plot from this values. I have no idea how to do this otherwise.

Comment: @Dani7Kaka - Removing three (3) records from each file will still leave you with 1,199,996,400 records. (1200 * 1000000) - (1200 * 3) Do you know if Matlab will handle a 1.2 M record file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sed, it's very easy. Starting from you folder, using the shell:

```
sed -ie '1,3d' *.csv
```

Before run it, do a backup of your files.

You can use sed also in windows, in several ways. One is to install it via chocolatey https://chocolatey.org/packages/sed

In windows the command is

```
for %i in (*.csv) do sed -i -e "1,3d" "%i"
```

Comment: I download sed and run your command like this: E:\myFolder1\myFolder2\myFolderWithCSV>sed -ie '1,3d' *.csv but I got back error: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\sed\tools\install\sed.exe: can't read *.csv: Invalid argument. I checked if I write everything correctly but I can't find mistake.

Comment: @Dani7Kaka I have edited my question, adding the windows command version

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PowerShell script that will do it. Yes, it is a little longer than a `sed` command, but most mortals can get the general idea of what it is doing pretty quickly. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell will be available without installing anything else.

```
$csvDirectory = 'C:\src\t'
$resultFile = 'C:\src\t\csvresult.txt'

if (Test-Path -Path $resultFile) { Remove-Item $resultFile }

Get-ChildItem -File -Path $csvDirectory -Filter '*.csv' |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-Content $_.FullName |
            Select-Object -Skip 3 |
            Out-File -FilePath $resultFile -Encoding ascii -Append
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You right that "sed" is shorter command but if I find a minute I will try your suggestion.